I want to write a section in arabic in an overleaf template but the rest of the document is written in english
I'm using an overleaf template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-faculty-of-engineering-ain-shams-university/ykvrxppdjqmz) to write my thesis and I wanted add a section written in arabic with some english words.
I tried adding some packages and trying to write it but neither of my trials were successful
How can I adjust this template to include this section
Main.tex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside,openright]{Thesis} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1} 
\input{Arabic summary}
\end{document}  


I don't know the missing packages to add to be able to create a section for my arabic summary

The best way is to use luatex with babel (IMHO). There are many answers on the site about this. Please read up on babel and ping me if you need more help.

@yannisl, I'm so grateful for you, sure will do

I posted a solution for you. This runs well on my laptop. I don't use overleaf, if you have any trouble running it there, ask for help here, as a number of overleaf staff, post  here as well. Also if you writing a thesis I would recommend you set up your own distribution on your own computer.

Can you recommend a particular setup ?
thank you for your cooperation.. @yannisl

I was a long time happy MikTeX user, but had numerous problems over the last 12 months and moved to texlive, which I recommend. If you on Linux texlive is also available.

You need to compile this with lualatex
I use babel including dad transliteration. texdoc dad for details, and please read the Babel documentation.

% lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iftranslit
\translittrue
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{panunicode}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic]{babel}
\iftranslit
\babelprovide[import,
  transforms=transliteration.dad,
  justification=kashida.plain, 
  onchar=ids fonts]{arabic}
 \else
  \babelprovide[import,
  onchar=ids fonts]{arabic}
  \fi
  
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Color=0000FF,Language=Arabic]{NotoSansArabic}
\babeltags{en = english, arab = Arabic}
\begin{document}

\section{Arabic transliteration { العصر}}

\textarab{sm`t SUtA hAtfA fY AlsH--Al'aUAn}

\bgroup
\let\arb\textarab
1. pharyngeal H = \textarab{H}, emphatic S = \arb{S}, D = \arb{D}, T = \arb{T}, Z = \arb{Z} and velar R = \arb R are 
uppercased—do not confuse them with glottal h = \arb h, non-emphatic s = s, d = \arb{d}, t =\arb t, z = \arb z, and alveolar r=\arb{r};\\
2. long vowels (A = \arb{A}, U = \arb{U}, Y = \arb{Y}) and ’alif maqṣūra (I = \arb I) are also uppercased.
\egroup

\begin{arab}
وان عدة الشهور عند الله اثنا عشر شهرا في كتاب الله يوم خلق السماوات والارض منها اربعة حرم ذلك الدين القيم فلاتظلموا فيهن انفسكم وقاتلوا المشركين كافة كما يقاتلونكم كافة واعلموا ان الله مع المتقين
\end{arab}

\end{document}

